# VBA Code Error - Query Table Name Keeps Changing

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a button in workbook A that is assigned to a macro. This macro exports a query from workbook A to another workbook, B. The goal is to replace the previous query in workbook B with the updated data. The macro works perfectly on the first run, but subsequent runs result in an error: 'Subscript out of range'. The error occurs because the query table in workbook B automatically changes its name from qry_ABB to qry_ABB1 or qry_ABB2, and so on. I'm seeking assistance on resolving this issue (The error resides on the line, Set targetQueryTable = targetWorkbook.Worksheets line, which makes sense because the name of the query on B changes each time the code is ran). I've attached the code down below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub ReplaceQueryTableWithRefreshedData()
    Dim currentWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim currentQueryTable As QueryTable
    Dim targetQueryTable As QueryTable

    ' Sets the path to the target workbook
    Dim targetWorkbookPath As String
    targetWorkbookPath = "C:\notgonnashow.xlsx"

    ' Sets the name of the target worksheet
    Dim targetWorksheetName As String
    targetWorksheetName = "qry_ABB"

    ' Opens the current workbook
    Set currentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook

    ' Sets the current query table
    Set currentQueryTable = currentWorkbook.Worksheets("qry_ABB").ListObjects("qry_ABB").QueryTable

    ' Opens the target workbook
    Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(targetWorkbookPath)

    ' Sets the target query table
    Set targetQueryTable = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(targetWorksheetName).ListObjects("qry_ABB").QueryTable
    
    
    Dim currentName As String
    currentName = targetWorkbook.Worksheets("qry_ABB").ListObjects("qry_ABB").Name
    ' Clears the existing data and properties of the target query table

    targetQueryTable.Delete
    
    ' Copies the query table from the current workbook to the target workbook
    currentQueryTable.ResultRange.Copy Destination:=targetWorkbook.Worksheets(targetWorksheetName).Range("A1")
    
 
   
    ' Saves and close the target workbook
    targetWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: If there's only one listobject on the sheet then you can use `ListObjects(1)` instead of using the name.